# Opencart ! Проблема с выводом городов

Tags: php, opencart

У меня такая задача:
На странице корзины выводить город, который пользователь выбирал.
В шапке сайта (на всех страницах) оно отображается и оттуда можно выбирать/менять город.
Данный код беру и вставляю на страницу корзинки, но там ничего не выводиться.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить данную проблему ? Спасибо!

P.S. Я не спец, не шарю в этом

Тот самый код:

```
<div class="prmn-cmngr__content">
        <div class="prmn-cmngr__title">
            <?= $text_zone ?>
            <a class="prmn-cmngr__city">
                <?= $city ?>
            </a>
        </div>
        <?= $confirm ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Если вы в этом не шарите, как вы сами говорите, зачем вы берётесь за это не разобравшись?

Answer (score 1):

У того файла, где берёте этот кусок кода (имеется в виду вью-файл, .tpl или .twig, вы не указали версию opencart) есть контроллер. В нём формируются переменные, которые потом реддерятся на фронте (`<?= $text_zone ?>` и т.д.). Ищите место, где `$data['text_zone']` или `$data['city']` или что-то похожее. Анализируете, как эта переменная собирается, какие модели задействует и т.п. и воспроизводите весь этот код в контроллере `корзинки`.